# Thumbnail for categories / taxonomies plugin?

Tags: categories, thumbnails

I'm looking for a nice way to attach an image as a thumbnail to a category. No plugin that I found does this.

I have a category loop and it would nice to display a category thumbnail, not just the name and description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [plugin Taxonomy Images](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-images/) by @mfields.

Answer (score 1):

I run a few rounds around this topic, and at last, I've found a plugin for this:

[Category Meta Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-category-meta/)

You can add nearly any kind of field to categories and taxonomies as well.

Comment: roscho suggested a better one for my website. You got one vote up from me anyway.